# ASP.net Authenticate with URL params in addition to Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, query-string, membership

My current ASP.net 3.5 site uses a Membership Provider to manage authentication for the entire site defined in the web.config.

I want to provide an additional method to authenticate by passing user params in the URL

ex. http://site.com?user=foo&pass=bar

What is the best method to achieve this, also this must be able to be invoked before the default authentication is invoked which is the problem I am running into now.

Comment: Are you certain you want to pass a password in plain text via querystring across the wire?

Comment: i understand the concern, but i am looking for a solution to the asked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Authentication redirects to Login.aspx. 
From there I can get the params from the **ReturnURL**

Then

```
//Check if Login Params are being sent via the URL
string user = Request.QueryString["user"];
string pass = Request.QueryString["pwd"];
if ((user != null) && (pass != null))
{
     this.Authenticate(user, pass);
}
//else continue with normal login method/form...
```